# Presenting ViewController anew does not re-initialize it

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

I have a viewController (videocallVC) that I want to initialize every time it comes into view/loads.
Currently, the videocallVC only initialize the first time.  If I leave the videocallVC, go to another viewController and come back to the videocallVC it holds the last session in memory and does not "refresh".

How can I make sure that every time I present the videocallVC it is initialized anew ?

```
import OpenTok

class videocallVC: UIViewController, OTSessionDelegate, OTSubscriberKitDelegate, OTPublisherDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var subscribeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var publishView: UIView!

    let apiKey = "xxxxxxx"

    var session : OTSession?
    var publisher : OTPublisher?
    var subscriber : OTSubscriber?
    var connection : OTConnection?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        session = OTSession(
            apiKey: apiKey,
            sessionId: variableInstance.sessionID,
            delegate: self)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        doConnect()
    }

    // MARK: - OpenTok Methods

    /**
    * Asynchronously begins the session connect process. Some time later, we will
    * expect a delegate method to call us back with the results of this action.
    */
    func doConnect() {
        if let session = self.session {
            var maybeError : OTError?
            session.connectWithToken(variableInstance.tokboxToken, error: &maybeError)
            if let error = maybeError {
                showAlert(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Sets up an instance of OTPublisher to use with this session. OTPubilsher
    * binds to the device camera and microphone, and will provide A/V streams
    * to the OpenTok session.
    */
    func doPublish() {
        publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self)

        var maybeError : OTError?
        session?.publish(publisher, error: &maybeError)

        if let error = maybeError {
            showAlert(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        view.addSubview(publisher!.view)
        publisher!.view.frame = publishView.frame

    }
```

There is more code to the videocallVC but I gues this is sufficient to understand the problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated !  Thank you.

Comment: Please add the tag for Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `viewDidLoad` is only called once. The method `viewWillAppear` is called every time the view will appear. So if you need to do things every time the view will appear, move it to that method (you may also use `viewDidAppear` if the UI behaviour makes sense). This may apply to the `session = OTSession( ... )` snippet.

It may also be possible, that in your code things get initialized, then stored in a variable and later, if the variable is not `nil` no new initialization is done. You may solve that by setting those variables to `nil` in `viewWillAppear`.

However, without knowing all details, this may be a likely solution but still a shot in the dark :-)

Comment: Thanks, your input helped.  Setting session, publisher, subscriber and connection  = nil together with self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(..) did the trick.  Thinking of it, I guess, putting it in viewDidDisappear might also work.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

how are your delegates store in OTSession and OTPublisher?

Are they weak?

If they are not weak, the View Controller can not be deinitialized, because there are still references to it. Maybe this can cause your problems.